# How to initiate an outgoing call from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I tried the following code. But the call is not sent properly. Any help on where I am going wrong will be great. I would like to capture the start and end timings of the call made as well.

```
 let provider = CXProvider(configuration: CXProviderConfiguration())
        provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
        let controller = CXCallController()
        let transaction = CXTransaction(action: CXStartCallAction(call: UUID(), handle: CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: ""))) // phonenumber value given
        controller.request(transaction, completion: { error in
            print(error)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 1) {
                        provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: controller.callObserver.calls[0].uuid, connectedAt: nil)
                    }
        })
```

Comment: Do you mean a cellular call using the mobile phone service?

Comment: Yes @Paulw11. I would like to let user make (normal)phone calls on select phone numbers. I also would like to know the start and end timing of the call.

Comment: You can make a call by opening a `tel:` url but you can't track the duration.   CallKit is for apps that implement VoIP calling using their own server